# Построить график, используя json данные js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я хотел бы построить график, чтобы он строился исходя из json данных, чтобы было типо как тут https://prnt.sc/Su7pBSkI4gEf, я имею ввиду, чтобы по оси у курс гривны исходя из валют доллара и евро, а по оси х дата, как менялся этот курс, я не очень понял, как правильно реализовать это, я видел много примеров, но они либо не работают, либо не то, что мне нужно, может я не правильный json поставил и надо этот было поставить https://bank.gov.ua/NBUStatService/v1/statdirectory/exchange?json

Поправочка: Я нашел тот JSON файл, который нужен, для отображение того, что я хотел, но он какой-то странный, но поскольку он идет не как ссылка, а как файл, то я к сожалению его к коду прикрепить не могу, поскольку не будет работать, а даже если и вставил бы этот код, он очень большой, и будет не очень, поэтому я лучше прикреплю скриншот, чтобы по нему было понятно https://prnt.sc/5ydo7jQ8RrGC

```js
async function fetchData() {
  const url = 'https://bank.gov.ua/NBU_Exchange/exchange?json';
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const datapoints = await response.json();
  console.log(datapoints);
  return datapoints;
};
// setup 
const data = {
  labels: ['Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul'],
  datasets: [{
      label: 'Dollars',
      data: [34, 33, 32, 31, 30, 29, 28, 27, 26],
      backgroundColor: [
        'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
      ],
      borderColor: [
        'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
        'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
        'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
        'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
        'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: "Euro",
      data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "#742774",
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
};


// config 
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options: {
    scales: {
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true
      }
    }
  }
};

// render init block
const myChart = new Chart(
  document.getElementById('myChart'),
  config,
);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.chartMenu p {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.chartCard {
  width: 100vw;
  height: calc(100vh - 1px);
  background: #B3E5FC;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.chartBox {
  width: 700px;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: solid 3px rgba(255, 26, 104, 1);
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="chartCard">
  <div class="chartBox">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    <button onclick='fetchData()'>Fetch</button>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
```

Comment: Во первых, действительно, лучше взять на вооружение второй json(), т к первый защищён, а второй нет. Во вторых, он выдаёт информацию только за текущий день, поэтому нужно будет каждый день запоминать текущий курс в БД, чтобы потом нарисовать график.

Comment: @Опан, во-первых, я там нашел JSON, который конкретно подходит, но не получится добавить сюда, посколько он идет как файл, а не ссылка, поэтому это только через редактор можно показать, а во-вторых, а как можно реализовать такое? Но я думаю БД не нужна тут, посколько все идет через JSON данные

Comment: Не должно быть разницы, делается запрос на страницу или один файл, если это файл с содержимым в формате json.

Comment: А можно картинку и пример json'а добавить в сам вопрос? А то без них ответить нереально...

Comment: @Qwertiy, Если вы про тот JSON, который действительно подходит, то я изменил свой вопрос, я добавил скриншот, но JSON странный на самом деле, кто так названия делает

Comment: @AndrewPhoenix, нет, я про ссылки в вопросе. У меня они не открываются...

Comment: В России не открываются многие украинские ссылки и наоборот - в Украине русские. Я дополнил ответ, теперь можно задействовать Ваш json(), который на скриншоте.

Comment: @Опан, воу, да, работает, я проверил, ставил разные json, со всеми работает, у кого есть такие данные, спасибо, Вам, большое, а как вот сделать, чтобы оно выглядело как вот у меня изначально, я имею ввиду, чтобы видно были все надписи, по иксу, игрику, там при наводке показывало то, ну вот как у меня вначале, у вопросе, надо ли в данных, где по иксу и игрику ставить данные из JSON, а то я не очень понял, как добавить, Ваш, код к этой библиотеке.

Comment: Я добавил ещё один ответ. Теперь задействован Ваш код из вопроса.

Comment: @Опан, Извините пожалуйста, что достаю, Вас, у Вас, там своих дел много, я бы хотел, чтобы некоторое осталось как тогда вы делали, тоесть, чтобы данные брались из того JSON, где вы переводили в текст его, тоесть, которые странный, а не из созданного, и когда вот по оси х, там метки должны быть месяцы, но при наводке, там чтобы показывало дату, например 26.06.2020, типо такое, можно такое? Если нужен JSON код, то вот https://jsfiddle.net/bf9jeoq8/12/. Еще раз извините.

Comment: Хорошо, вечером сделаю.

Comment: @Я сделал, только метки в виде месяцев не получаются. Вместо этого отображаются даты, только не все, а выборочно с определённым шагом. А при наведении выводятся все даты. Я подумал не создавать новый ответ, так как гражданам других стран кроме Украины он будет мало полезен, поэтому код находится по [этой ссылке](https://github.com/mysynthesizer/index.hetemeel/blob/main/schedule.txt)

Comment: @Опан, спасибо большое, у меня тоже так получилось как у вас, только по предыдущему примеру, там я кароче, вручную изменял некоторые названия в самом JSON, это конечно жесть была, но в итоге нормально, работает,но меня просто смущало, даты эти, поэтому еще раз к вам обратился, но это наверное из-за самой библиотеки связано, в любом случае, спасибо большое

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, я состыковал Ваш вопрос и мой первый ответ. Используйте JS-код ниже, а HTML и CSS-коды оставьте такими, как были в вопросе.

```js
async function fetchData() {
    const url = 'https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/json3.json';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const datapoints = await response.json();
    console.log(datapoints);
    const dates = [];
    const dollars = [];
    const euro = [];
    for(i = 0; i < datapoints.length; i ++){
        dates[i] = datapoints[i].date;
        dollars[i] = datapoints[i].usd;
        euro[i] = datapoints[i].eur;
    }
    const data = {
        labels: dates,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Dollars', 
                data: dollars,
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 26, 104, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)',
                    'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)'
                ],
                borderColor: [
                    'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)',
                    'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                    'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                    'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                    'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)',
                    'rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)'
                ],
                borderWidth: 1
            },
            {
                label: "Euro",
                data: euro,
                fill: false,
                borderColor: "#742774",
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
    };

    // config 
    const config = {
        type: 'line', 
        data,
        options: {
            scales: {
                y: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }
        }
    };

    // render init block
    const myChart = new Chart(
        document.getElementById('myChart'),
        config,
    );
};
fetchData();
```

Содержимое файла **json3.json**:

```js
[
    { 
        "date": 17, "usd": 27.12, "eur": 25.42
    },{
        "date" :18, "usd": 28.55, "eur": 23.18
    },{ 
        "date": 19, "usd": 30.72, "eur": 22.17
    },{
        "date": 20, "usd": 33.43, "eur": 22.09
    },{ 
        "date": 21, "usd": 31.12, "eur": 18.82
    },{
        "date": 22, "usd": 29.22, "eur": 25.77
    },{ 
        "date": 23, "usd": 25.12, "eur": 27.22
    },{
        "date": 24 ,"usd": 23.88, "eur": 33.45
    },{ 
        "date": 25, "usd": 24.76, "eur": 34.24
    },{
        "date": 26, "usd": 24.22, "eur": 31.01
    }
]
```

Правда, кнопка **Fetch** теперь не очень нужна, так как график рисуется по ходу загрузки страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Этот пример рисует график используя данные удалённого файла в формате json:

```js
async function fetchData() {
    const url = 'https://mysynthesizer.github.io/index.hetemeel/json.json';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const datapoints = await response.json();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, datapoints[0].rate * 3);
    for(i = 1; i < datapoints.length; i ++){
        ctx.lineTo(i * 30, 200 - datapoints[i].rate * 3);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
fetchData();
let ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

```html
<canvas width=270 height=200 style='border-style: solid'><canvas>
```

Содержимое удалённого файла **json.json**:

```js
[
    { 
        "date": 17, "rate": 27.12
    },{
        "date" :18, "rate": 28.55
    },{ 
        "date": 19, "rate": 30.72
    },{
        "date": 20, "rate": 33.43
    },{ 
        "date": 21, "rate": 31.12
    },{
        "date": 22, "rate": 29.22
    },{ 
        "date": 23, "rate": 25.12
    },{
        "date": 24 ,"rate": 23.88
    },{ 
        "date": 25, "rate": 24.76
    },{
        "date": 26, "rate": 24.22
    }
]
```

Дополняю ответ после изменения вопроса. Да, наличие украиноязычных ключей немножко вызвало проблему, но из такого всегда можно выкрутиться. В данном случае ответ сервера нужно получить не в виде json(), а в виде текста. Потом заменить в этом тексте все украинские выражения на английские, в данном случае **Дата** и **Офіційний курс гривні, грн** соответственно, скажем, на **date** и **rate**. После этого остаётся преобразовать весь текст, который получился, в массив **json()** и дальше всё по плану.

```js
async function fetchData() {
    const url = 'https://[Ваш json(), который на скриншоте]';
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const text_ua = await response.text();
    const text_en = text_ua.replaceAll('Дата', 'date').replaceAll('Офіційний курс гривні, грн', 'rate');
    const datapoints = JSON.parse(text_en);
    const step = 300 / (datapoints.length - 1);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, datapoints[0].rate * 3);
    for(i = 1; i < datapoints.length; i ++){
        ctx.lineTo(Math.floor(i * step), 200 - datapoints[i].rate * 3);
    }
    ctx.stroke();
}
fetchData();
let ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
```

```html
<canvas width=300 height=200 style='border-style: solid'><canvas>
```